# Using constants in SQL Query activities?

Tags: marketing-cloud, automationstudio

for a particular automation that runs daily I have several SQL query activities that rely on the same integer in their SQL queries, a hardcoded "-1".  Sometimes I need to manually run this automation with a different constant (say -2), which involves me needing to alter each of the SQL queries, changing the -1 to -2, running the automation, and then changing them each back to -1.

What I'd like to do is store a constant in one place and have those queries reference that constant instead, so if I need to change the constant I only need to do that in one place.  Does Automation Studio provide support for that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not just create a separate data extension for your parameters and join to it? You can manually update the parameters DE as needed (or use a query update it).  I frequently do that with date ranges for the exact reason you're describing.

**Date_Parameters**

| AutomationKey | StartDate | EndDate |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ExpiringSoon | 2022-04-24 | 2022-04-26 |

(AutomationKey is a primary key)

**All_Contacts**

| SubscriberKey | EmailAddress | FirstName | SubscriptionEndDate |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1111 | adam@example.com | Adam | 2022-04-25 |

**Query**

```sql
select
  m.SubscriberKey
, m.EmailAddress
, m.FirstName
, m.SubscriptionEndDate
from All_Contacts m
inner join Date_Parameters p on p.AutomationKey = 'ExpiringSoon'
where m.subscriptionEndDate >= convert(date, p.StartDate)
and m.subscriptionEndDate <= convert(date, p.EndDate)
```